# Makefile error in Pythia

Tags: c++, macos, makefile

When I use the Makefile in the examples folder of Pythia8185 I get an error (ME below!):

ME: This is mymain.cc

```
#include "Pythia8/Pythia.h" // Include Pythia headers.
using namespace Pythia8; // Let Pythia8:: be implicit.
int main() { // Begin main program.
    // Set up generation.
    Pythia pythia; // Declare Pythia object
    pythia.readString("Top:gg2ttbar = on"); // Switch on process.
    pythia.readString("Beams:eCM = 7000."); // 7 TeV CM energy.
    pythia.init(); // Initialize; incoming pp beams is default.
    // Generate event(s).
    pythia.next(); // Generate an(other) event. Fill event record.
    return 0;
} // End main program with error-free return.
```

This is the Makefile before edit:

```
#
# Examples Makefile.
#
#                  M. Kirsanov 07.04.2006
#                     Modified 18.11.2006
#                     26.03.2008 CLHEP dependency removed

SHELL = /bin/sh

-include config.mk
ifeq (x$(PYTHIA8LOCATION),x)
 PYTHIA8LOCATION=..
endif
-include $(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/config.mk

# Location of directories.
TOPDIR=$(shell \pwd)
INCDIR=include
SRCDIR=src
LIBDIR=lib
LIBDIRARCH=lib/archive
BINDIR=bin

# Libraries to include if GZIP support is enabled
ifeq (x$(ENABLEGZIP),xyes)
LIBGZIP=-L$(BOOSTLIBLOCATION) -lboost_iostreams -L$(ZLIBLOCATION) -lz
endif

# There is no default behaviour, so remind user.
all:
    @echo "Usage: for NN = example number: make mainNN"

# Create an executable for one of the normal test programs
main00  main01 main02 main03 main04 main05 main06 main07 main08 main09 main10 \
    main11 main12 main13 main14 main15 main16 main17 main18 main19 main20 \
    main21 main22 main23 main24 main25 main26 main27 main28 main29 main30 \
    main31 main32 main33 main34 main35 main36 main37 main38 main39 main40 \
    main80: \
    $(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH)/libpythia8.a
    @mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(INCDIR) $@.cc -o $(BINDIR)/$@.exe \
    -L$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH) -lpythia8 -llhapdfdummy $(LIBGZIP)
    @ln -fs $(BINDIR)/$@.exe $@.exe

# Create an executable linked to HepMC (if all goes well).
# Owing to excessive warning output -Wshadow is not used for HepMC.
ifneq (x$(HEPMCLOCATION),x)
  main41 main42: \
    $(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH)/libpythia8.a $(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH)/libpythia8tohepmc.a
    @mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -Wno-shadow -I$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(INCDIR) -I$(HEPMCLOCATION)/include \
    $@.cc -o $(BINDIR)/$@.exe \
    -L$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH) -lpythia8 -llhapdfdummy $(LIBGZIP) \
    -lpythia8tohepmc \
    -L$(HEPMCLOCATION)/lib -lHepMC
    @ln -fs $(BINDIR)/$@.exe $@.exe
else
  main41 main42:
    @echo ERROR, this target needs HepMC, variable HEPMCLOCATION
endif

# Create an executable that links to LHAPDF
main51 main52 main53 main54: $(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH)/libpythia8.a
    @mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(INCDIR) $@.cc -o $(BINDIR)/$@.exe \
    -L$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH) -lpythia8 $(LIBGZIP) \
    -L$(LHAPDFLOCATION) $(LHAPDFLIBNAME) \
    $(FLIBS)
    @ln -fs $(BINDIR)/$@.exe $@.exe

# Create an executable that links to LHAPDF and HepMC
main61 main62 main85 main86 main87 main88: \
    $(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH)/libpythia8.a $(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH)/libpythia8tohepmc.a
    @mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -Wno-shadow -I$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(INCDIR) -I$(HEPMCLOCATION)/include \
    $@.cc -o $(BINDIR)/$@.exe \
    -L$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH) -lpythia8 -lpythia8tohepmc $(LIBGZIP) \
    -L$(LHAPDFLOCATION) $(LHAPDFLIBNAME) \
    -L$(HEPMCLOCATION)/lib -lHepMC \
    $(FLIBS)
    @ln -fs $(BINDIR)/$@.exe $@.exe

# Create an executable that links to Fastjet
# Owing to excessive warning output -Wshadow is not used for Fastjet.
# (Fixed as of Fastjet 3.0.1, so will be modified eventually.)
ifneq (x$(FASTJETLOCATION),x)
  main71 main72: $(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH)/libpythia8.a
    @mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    # Note: $(CXXFLAGS) is after Fastjet flags as Fastjet includes
    #       optimisation/debug flags which may be unwanted (e.g. -g -O2)
    $(CXX) -I$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(INCDIR) $@.cc \
    `$(FASTJETLOCATION)/bin/fastjet-config --cxxflags --plugins` \
    $(CXXFLAGS) -Wno-shadow \
    -o $(BINDIR)/$@.exe \
    -L$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH) -lpythia8 -llhapdfdummy $(LIBGZIP) \
    -L$(FASTJETLOCATION)/lib \
    `$(FASTJETLOCATION)/bin/fastjet-config --libs --plugins`
    @ln -fs $(BINDIR)/$@.exe $@.exe
    @rm -f $@.o
else
  main71 main72:
    @echo ERROR, this target needs Fastjet, variable FASTJETLOCATION
endif

# Create an executable that links to Fastjet, HepMC and LHApdf
# Owing to excessive warning output -Wshadow is not used for Fastjet.
# (Fixed as of Fastjet 3.0.1, so will be modified eventually.)
ifneq (x$(FASTJETLOCATION),x)
  main81 main82 main83 main84: \
    $(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH)/libpythia8.a  $(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH)/libpythia8tohepmc.a
    @mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    # Note: $(CXXFLAGS) is after Fastjet flags as Fastjet includes
    #       optimisation/debug flags which may be unwanted (e.g. -g -O2)
    $(CXX) -I$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(INCDIR) $@.cc \
    `$(FASTJETLOCATION)/bin/fastjet-config --cxxflags --plugins` \
    $(CXXFLAGS) -Wno-shadow \
    -I$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(INCDIR) -I$(HEPMCLOCATION)/include \
    -o $(BINDIR)/$@.exe \
    -L$(PYTHIA8LOCATION)/$(LIBDIRARCH) -lpythia8 \
    -L$(LHAPDFLOCATION) $(LHAPDFLIBNAME) \
    -lpythia8tohepmc \
    -L$(HEPMCLOCATION)/lib -lHepMC \
    -L$(FASTJETLOCATION)/lib \
    -L$(LHAPDFLOCATION)/lib \
    `$(FASTJETLOCATION)/bin/fastjet-config --libs --plugins`
    @ln -fs $(BINDIR)/$@.exe $@.exe
    @rm -f $@.o
else
  main81 main82 main83 main84:
    @echo ERROR, this target needs Fastjet, variable FASTJETLOCATION
endif

# Clean up: remove executables and outdated files.
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(BINDIR)
    rm -rf *.exe
    rm -f *~; rm -f \#*; rm -f core*
```

After edit I add `mymain:` just after `main80` and then I write make mymain and get the error as follows:

I edit the Makefile and add mymain to the list:

```
# Create an executable for one of the normal test programs
 main00 main01 main02 main03 main04 main05 main06 main07 main08 main09 main10 \
        main11 main12 main13 main14 main15 main16 main17 main18 main19 main20 \
        main21 main22 main23 main24 main25 main26 main27 main28 main29 main30 \
        main31 main32 main33 main34 main35 main36 main37 main38 main39 main40 \
        main80 mymain: \
```

as [suggested in the worksheet example page 4.](http://home.thep.lu.se/~torbjorn/pythia81html/worksheet.pdf#page=4)

Then when I write `make mymain` in the Terminal I get the following error:

```
*** No rule to make target `../lib/archive/libpythia8.a', needed by `mymain'.  Stop.
```

It should be noted that everything worked fine yesterday, I really don't know how to proceed. I deleted all pythia folders and untarred them again but the problem remains. Anyone know what the solution might be? I'm on a MacBook.

Is there a way to uninstall something like pythia completely and reinstall it? It seems some file in some cache is the problem

Comment: It would help if you showed us the complete (minimal) makefile.

Comment: Do you have `libpythia8.a`? Where is it, and where in which directory do you execute Make?

Comment: I execute in the examples folder.

Comment: Are the other main<xx> examples working?

Comment: This was long time ago so I don't recall. I had to use a windows machine to solve the problem in the end... Shame.